Lemon concentrate fermenting
I'm trying to ferment leman concentrate ph was at5.4 at the start using yeast nurthail and dady yeast gravity was at 1.1 it doesn't want to get started fermenting temp is 83 any help

Can you provide any more information?

4 days and its not bubbling or anything poped the lid nothing

It is not uncommon for home brewer's fermentation setup to not hold pressure well (e.g., plastic bucket with an airlock in a hole in the lid might be leaky around the main lid seal). If you are seeing your airlock bubbling, then you know that your yeast is hard at work. However, if you do not see bubbling, it might be a yeast problem OR it might be a leaky seal. The SURE way to know if your yeast is working or not is to measure your specific gravity over a period of time.

So, go ahead and measure your specific gravity now and hit the "edit" button on your post and include this additional information. We will try to help interpret the result.
